# Does the $\Omega$-spectrum functor send exact triangles to homotopy cofiber sequences?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The functor $\Omega^\infty\colon Spectra\to Spaces$ which takes a spectrum, replaces it by the associated $\Omega$-spectrum and then takes its $0$th space sends exact triangles to homotopy fiber sequences.

> Does $\Omega^\infty$ send exact triangles of spectra to homotopy cofiber
>   sequences of spaces?

For spectra, homotopy cofiber sequences, homotopy fiber sequences and exact triangles are the same.

Comment: Hi, do you have a reference for the 1st statement that $\Omega^{\infty}$ sends exact triangles to htpy fiber sequences ?

Comment: Hi Bogdan, $\Omega^\infty$ is in fact the right derived functor of the evaluation of a spectrum at it's $0$-th level (the fibrant replacement that has to be done to obtain that right derived functor is the $\operatorname{colim} \Omega^k X_k$-construction you know). Right Quillen functors preserve homotopy fiber sequences.

Comment: That is cool. I was seeing $\Omega^{\infty}$ as the left adjoint to inclusion of $\Omega$-spectra in Spectra. And so this left adjoint agrees with fibrant replacement, there is no mistake here, right ? It's interesting

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it doesn't, which kinda makes sense since it is a composite of a left and a right adjoint.

More precisely : takes a short exact sequence of abelian groups $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$, then you get an exact triangle of spectra $HA \to HB \to HC$. If you rotate, or suspend once you get $\Sigma HA \to \Sigma HB \to \Sigma HC$ which is also exact, but the $0$-spaces are $K(A,1) \to K(B,1) \to K(C,1)$, i.e., the classifying spaces $BA \to BB \to BC$.

Now, the functor $B(-)$  sends short exact sequences of discrete abelian groups to fiber sequences but not cofiber sequences, for example take $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cdot 2}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0$ which becomes $S^1 \to S^1 \to RP^{\infty}$ which is not a cofiber sequence as can be seen in homology.